# Replacing change multiples values in a Dataframe Column (Datetime column)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a dataframe that i'm **webscraping** from Linkedind and im trying to solve the date problem.

I have this head:

[imag_head_dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hl5bx.png)

I want to change the values of this column:

```
(Original values)               (Values that i need - datetime type)
    Data Posted 
    27 minutos                       1-8-2021
    18 horas                         1-8-2021
    1 dia                            1-8-2021
    1 mês                            1-7-2021
    2 meses                          1-6-2021
```

I've tried a lot of methods to change this date column, but nothing is working.

Could you help me?

```
    ....
```

Comment: How is it "nothing is working"? What have you tried and what did you get? And what is datatype of original column?

Comment: Thank you, its resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use `dateparser`:

```
# Python env: pip install dateparser
# Anaconda env: conda install dateparser

import dateparser
from datetime import datetime

NOW = datetime.now()

data = {'Data Posted': ['27 minutos', '18 horas', '1 dia', '1 mês', '2 meses']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Delta'] = datetime.now() - df['Data Posted'].apply(dateparser.parse)
```

```
>>> df
  Data Posted                   Delta
0  27 minutos  0 days 00:26:59.993440
1    18 horas  0 days 17:59:59.991212
2       1 dia  0 days 23:59:59.989509
3       1 mês 30 days 23:59:59.986321
4     2 meses 60 days 23:59:59.984035
```